# Remove data from core data using UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, uilocalnotification

I am trying to remove a data from code data model when local notification is fired. So I get notifications's `alertbody` ,then  fetch sort data using notification title :

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?,
                     forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {


        if identifier == "deleteEvent" {

            context = CoreDataStack.managedObjectContext

            do {

                request =  NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Event")
                let titlePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[c] %@" ,notification.alertBody!)

                request.predicate = titlePredicate
                results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

                print(results.count) // returns 1



            } catch {

                print("ERROR")
            }

                do {

                    results.removeAtIndex(0)
                    CoreDataStack.saveContext()

                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadTableView", object: nil)
                    print(results.count) // returns 0

            }


        }

        completionHandler()
    }
```

when I remove the data from the model and go to event view controller for example still I can see the data is there !  Am I missing something ?! thanks.

Comment: @santa would you check this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing an element from the `results` array (using `removeAtIndex`) does not delete it from the persistent store - or even from the context.  You need to tell the context to delete the object:

```
let object = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
context.deleteObject(object)
```